# Error Reporting when translating between ASTs

Tags: rascal

I'm doing some translations between two ADTs but when I use data types that don't exist in the current scope it doesn't throw any errors, any suggestions on how to fix this?

EDIT:

Context: Say I have the following module to translate some SQL constructs to HQL, in the context below, the `Python` construct doesn't exist in this scope, but I don't get the error report or linting.

```
module lang::sql::translations::translate2b::TranslateDML

import lang::sql::ast::SQL;
import lang::hql::ast::Module;

extend lang::sql::translations::translate2b::TranslateExpressions;


public HQL translateDeclaration(Python sqlCmd) {
  switch(sqlCmd) {
    default: throw "Unhandled HQL: <sqlCmd>";
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you give a small example? That would help us understand the specific problem.

Comment: Could be a setup error were the type-checker fails to run at all. Or a leaky type environment; but those were bugs we had in the earliest alpha versions in 2009...

Comment: I added some context in an edit. @DavyLandman

Comment: if you'd add a global variable like this: `int x = "not an int";` does it at least complain about that?

Comment: No, it doesn't. https://res.cloudinary.com/fellyr/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto/fzco3fcrnrscgzyqsjvo

Comment: Anytime I change something, the 'Rascal Check' icon just flashes for a moment, and then nothing happens.